# How to set dom's text in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to set dom's text in pure javascript?
I want to set ul object's text value.
So i tried below.

```
getElementByID("DropDown").textContent = "text";
```

But the ul's child is disappeared when i set the textcontent.
It has same result in innerHtml and innerText.

```
getElementByID("DropDown").innerText= "text";
getElementByID("DropDown").innerHtml= "text";
```

Then i must appendChild(TextNode) to ul? I think it is too complex.
I must append TextNode and i must save the TextNode's ref. 
Is there have any easy way?

Comment: A ul is a container for lis, not for text.

Comment: You may want to add some relevant HTML snippet too. That "But the ul's child is disappeared" part is not very clean. ```ul``` has no text, it has ```li```-s: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp . Perhaps you want to append new elements to an existing list? Then yes, ```appendChild``` can help. but you also need ```createElement```.

Comment: The component 'DropDown' is a html select. If yes 'text' means selection is it?

Comment: I have a big misunderstanding about ul tag. 
I means that <ul> <li>1</li> <li>2</li></ul>.
And i set textcontent to ul(like a title text). oh...no.... maybe i guess textcontent wrapped
<li>1</li> <li>2</li> .

Thanks for answering.
Sam Axe
tevemadar
janith1024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` is just a string. If you overwrite it, it loses its previous content. But, you can append to it instead, and then it does not lose its previous content. See `magic1`
And `magic2` shows the `createElement`+`appendChild` way. While it has more lines, it is easier to manage if you want to set various attributes of an element (style, event handlers and others - not necessarily for this particular case of list items, but in general).

```js
var i=0;
function magic1(){
  i++;
  document.getElementById("myUL").innerHTML+="<li>Testx"+i+"</li>";
}
function magic2(){
  i++;
  var li=document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML="Testy"+i;
  document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="magic1()">ClickMe1</button>
<button onclick="magic2()">ClickMe2</button>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```